# How do I preserve symlinks when unzipping an archive using Python?

Tags: python

Many zip archives (especially those include OS X applications) contain symlinks. When using the `zipfile.extractall` method, symlinks are turned into regular files. Anyone know how to preserve them as links?

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be no way to do this using the zipfile module.  I solved it using the subprocess module:

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError, STDOUT

try:
   check_output(['unzip', '-q', my_zipfile, '-d', destination], stderr=STDOUT)
```

...

```
except CalledProcessError as err:
   (use err.cmd, err.returncode and err.output to take action)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using the [extractall](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) method. You'll need to do it manually, probably ending with something looking [something like this](http://doeidoei.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/compressing-files-with-python-symlink-trouble/) (except you're extracting not compressing).

Answer (score -2):

Using Mark Lutz's [ziptools](https://learning-python.com/ziptools/ziptools.zip), you can zip and extract zip with symlink intact.

try:

```
import ziptools

ziptools.extractzipfile('include-symlink.zip', './output-folder')
```

Credits to Mark Lutz: https://learning-python.com/ziptools.html

Comment: This tool no longer functions with a recent python (3.9.5). Specifically, it requires a relative path import syntax that is no onger supported and I wasn't brave enough to continue to try to use it after that point since there didn't even seem to be an official way to file bugs from that page.